# Python Serial: How to use the read or readline function to read more than 1 character at a time

Tags: python, serial-port, readline, pyserial

I'm having trouble to read more than one character using my program, I can't seem to figure out what went wrong with my program.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM5',\
    baudrate=9600,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=0)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)
count=1

while True:
    for line in ser.read():

        print(str(count) + str(': ') + chr(line) )
        count = count+1

ser.close()
```

here are the results I get

```
connected to: COM5
1: 1
2: 2
3: 4
4: 3
5: 1
```

actually I was expecting this

```
connected to: COM5
1:12431
2:12431
```

something like the above mentioned which is able read multiple characters at the same time not one by one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564715/serial-port-getting-engaged-after-reading-single-command-in-python Please can anyone guide me on this

Comment: Of all the documentation I found, nobody specified that I should be writing "port = 'COM5'" instead of just dev/usb0 or similar. Thank you!

Answer (score 36):

I see a couple of issues.

First:

ser.read() is only going to return 1 byte at a time.

If you specify a count

```
ser.read(5)
```

it will read 5 bytes  (less if timeout occurrs before 5 bytes arrive.)

If you know that your input is always properly terminated with EOL characters,
 better way is to use

```
ser.readline()
```

That will continue to read characters until an EOL is received.

Second:

Even if you get ser.read() or ser.readline() to return multiple bytes,
since you are iterating over the return value, you will
still be handling it one byte at a time.

Get rid of the

```
for line in ser.read():
```

and just say:

```
line = ser.readline()
```

Comment: Hi, when I'm using line=ser.readline() , it always ask me for an integer                                                           print(str(count) + str(': ') + chr(line) )
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: chr(line) is expecting an integer argument. You're giving it a string.

Answer (score 21):

I use this small method to read Arduino serial monitor with Python

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("COM11", 9600)
while True:
     cc=str(ser.readline())
     print(cc[2:][:-5])
```

Comment: Nice, I needed to clean that response, good one! I think for future readers it's worth mentioning in your answer what exactly your code performs.

Comment: I assume you use `cc[2:][:-5]` to strip the `b'` and `\r\n'`. Wouldn't it be better to use `.decode("utf-8")` for this?

Answer (score 12):

Serial sends data 8 bits at a time, that translates to 1 byte and 1 byte means 1 character.

You need to implement your own method that can read characters into a buffer until some sentinel is reached. The convention is to send a message like `12431\n` indicating one line.

So what you need to do is to implement a buffer that will store X number of characters and as soon as you reach that `\n`, perform your operation on the line and proceed to read the next line into the buffer.

***Note*** you will have to take care of buffer overflow cases i.e. when a line is received that is longer than your buffer etc...

***EDIT***

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM5',\
    baudrate=9600,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=0)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

#this will store the line
line = []

while True:
    for c in ser.read():
        line.append(c)
        if c == '\n':
            print("Line: " + ''.join(line))
            line = []
            break

ser.close()
```

Comment: Hi, could you give me some guide on the buffering? I'm really confused right now.

Comment: I edited the code, take a look. Just remember one thing, the code above will KEEP reading into the `line` array until it sees a `\n` character so make sure in your serial device sends a `\n`.

Comment: Hi, the codes aboves doesn't seems to work. it says char is not defined.

Comment: Try now, i had char when i should have had 'c', just make sure ur serial program does indeed send '\n' characters after each line

Comment: "You need to implement your own method that can read characters into a buffer until some sentinel is reached" - isn't this *exactly* what `serial.readline` does?

Answer (score 6):

I was reciving some date from my arduino uno (0-1023 numbers).
Using code from 1337holiday, jwygralak67 and some tips from other sources:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM4',\
    baudrate=9600,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=0)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

#this will store the line
seq = []
count = 1

while True:
    for c in ser.read():
        seq.append(chr(c)) #convert from ANSII
        joined_seq = ''.join(str(v) for v in seq) #Make a string from array

        if chr(c) == '\n':
            print("Line " + str(count) + ': ' + joined_seq)
            seq = []
            count += 1
            break


ser.close()
```

Comment: I think your comment 
#convert from ansii 
should be
#convert from ascii

Comment: This chr(c) made it for me after few days of turning around the problem. I have an ATTiny85 sending an int to an ATTiny45 sending this data to a Raspberry Pi 0. all using serial communication. I was just checking why it was displaying 48 when I was sending 0. ASCII was published in 1963. Always, back to the source. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A bit different:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM5',
    baudrate=115200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=0
)

print("Connected to:", ser.portstr)

array_tmp = []

while True:
    byte_read = ser.read()  # Read bytes from serial port
    if byte_read:#if not empty
        byte_char = byte_read.decode()  # Decode bytes to string
        array_tmp.append(byte_char)
        if byte_char == '\n':
            print(''.join(array_tmp))  # Print the received line
            print(array_tmp)  # Print the received line
            array_tmp = []

ser.close()
```