# serial port getting engaged after reading single command in python

Tags: python, serial-port, readline, pyserial

I am making a connection with python using `pyserial` with a UART port. As I send the command using `serial.write` my output is received but my serial port does not break connection. As I need to send a second command also to receive the output.  Please guide me on this.

I have also used `ser.close` still I am not able to close the port.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
        port='COM5', \
        baudrate=9600, \
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, \
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, \
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, \
        timeout= 10)
print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

ser.write(b'\reeprom\r')
seq = []
count = 1

while True:
        for c in ser.readline():
            seq.append(chr(c))  # convert from ANSII
            joined_seq = ''.join(str(v) for v in seq)  # Make a string from array

            if chr(c) == '\n':
                print("Line " + str(count) + ': ' + joined_seq)
                seq = []
                count += 1
                break

ser.close()
```

Can you please guide what is going wrong. I am expecting that I should get my output of the fired command to UART and then code should exit rather than continue running. Also I wanted to know if this works can I again make connection and fire the second command to UART. Please help me on this.

Comment: Did you tool a look at the warning about the readline function: https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#readline

Comment: @vermaete yes i have seen this and already added timeout to my code but  doesnt  seem it is working for me.

Comment: @vermaete as i am new in using uart with python. can you please help me how to deal with this issue.

Comment: @vermaete i have even placed timeout and serial.close . but none is working for me . can you help on this ??